# Hibernate gets objcets over and over in a endless loop

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I guess I'm doing something wrong with Hibernate and how I wrote the entities because when I try to get an object that contains another object they started getting each other over and over. Also when `toString` method which should return all fields in a string is called I got a stackoverflow error.

`Instructor` can only have one `InstructorDetail` and various `Course`, it's working more or less as expected but something is off.

Instructor class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_table")
public class Instructor {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="instructor_id")
    private int instructorId;
    
    @Column(name="instructor_name")
    private String instructorName;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="instructor", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="instructor", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Course> courses;
```

InstructorDetail class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_detail_table")
public class InstructorDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="instructor_detail_id")
    private int instructorDetailId;
    
    @Column(name="instructor_class")
    private String instructorDetailClass;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;
```

Course class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="course_table")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="course_id")
    private int courseId;
    
    @Column(name="course_class")
    private String course_class;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;
```

[image: Endless loop getting entities on Imgur.]

Comment: This is probably due to your model `Instructor` refers to `InstructorDetail`, which in turn refers to `Instructor`. As a solution, you can use `instructor_id` in `InstructorDetail`

Comment: add code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your relationships defined in both directions, so trying to recursively evaluate every property will always be an infinite loop.

```
instructor -> instructorDetail -> instructor -> instructorDetail -> ...
```

You need to exclude one of the directions from your `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` implementations, or otherwise change them to break the chain. Which way around you do it is up to you, and your definition of object equality.

Or, simply don't define them in both directions.

Comment: Fixed in that Instructor - InstructorDetail relationship. I guess I didn't understand how to use mappedBy or when exactly it should be used.